# How to deal with Errors or Prevent them in PHP

Tags: php, exception

I wrote a program and it really needs better Error Handling because f.e. when the program fetches Data over an API it produces tons of errors and I don't really handle them correctly.

I am wondering how I do that correctly.

let's assume function a() fetches an array from a mysql database.
Now it returns that array so that function x() can call that function.

Do I now check in function x() if the return value of a() is actually not empty and of type array?
Or do I do that in x()

My code as tons of function calls and I'm really unsure how to deal with all the errors it can produce. 
Because what if we make the valid check in a() how should x() now react now that it knows a() doesn't return an array

I know about catch and exceptions and such in PHP, but how do I utilize them correctly?

Comment: Use try catch http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I know about catch and exceptions and such in PHP, but how do I utilize them correctly?

Comment: When fetching data from a database, set up the variable into which you'll be placing the result set as an array before the function or loop which will load data into it. Then if whatever is acting on the result set expects an array, if there was no results returned but the query exectuted ok, it'll see an empty array